# Get recent added lines from a file.txt c++

Tags: c++, file

I want to read recent added lines in a file.txt with c++ . Everytime I add some new lines in the file I want to read just those recent lines.

This code below just read all the lines of the file

```
void Reading::read(const char* path)
{
    string str_path = string(path);
    string str;
    ifstream file1(path);
    if(str_path.substr(str_path.find_last_of(".")+ 1)== "jrn")
    {
        if(file1.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(file1, str)) 
            {
                cout << str << "\n";
            }
            file1.close();
        }
        else
            cout <<"File not found " << endl;

        file1.close();
        }
    else
    {
        cout << "Can't read this type of file" << endl;
    }
}
```

Please can you help me to solve the problem . Thank you .

Comment: Depends on what you consider "recently added". In general you won't have a version history of the file available. If you meant the last lines in the file: The simple approach would be to just read the strings to a collection after the collection is full, the more complex but probably more performant version would be to read the last parts of the end of the file to a buffer until you've found enough line breaks and then reading forward from the appropriate position...

Comment: What is adding these lines? If it's another program, your options are limited.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `Reading` class cache the return value from `file1.tellg()`, call `file1.seekg()` to go to the last read location before reading the lines.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/